# Manage Instances of the same Service

Tags: java, android

I was wondering if someone here can help me with an issue: 
I have this background service running that starts when the phone boots and, from then, every 15 min.
I want this same service to also start when i click the app icon. Is there any way i can manage the service's instances so I am 100% sure that only one instance of the service is running? I mean, I want to make sure that I only start one Service instance. 
Sorry for the question but I'm a beginner and searched everywhere for this and still couldn't fine an exact answer for this issue (or maybe I'm the one that doesn't know how to look). If this question is already answered I'm sorry.

Cheers.

Comment: 1 service is only created once. Any later call dont re-create the service.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend reading up on Services here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html.

To answer your question.  Only a single instance of a service is ever running at one time.  When you call `startService()`, If the service doesn't exist, it's created and the `onStartCommand()` is invoked.  If the service already exists though, then only the `onStartCommand()` method is invoked.  It will be your responsibility in `onStartCommand()` to determine if whatever operation you're running is currently running.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your reply. So I need to override onStartCommand()?